# How to write a "while-else" condition in one line in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to reduce the following code to one single line:

```
while not is_ok: 
    pass
else:
    print('a')
time.sleep(0.5)
```

I tried this:

```
while not is_ok: pass; else: print('a')
time.sleep(0.5)
```

But it's wrong.

Any ideas?

**Clarification**: I am using multithreading. The `is_ok` variable is a shared boolean between Threads that will eventually change its value.

Comment: Why are you using an `else` block at all if you don't have a `break`? If you just want to do something after a loop, the standard way to do that is to put it after the loop.

Comment: Why do you need a `while` ? If there is a requirement for loop on condition use `if` and `while` nested.

Comment: Is this an exam question or a real world problem?

Comment: It sounds like you should be waiting on a condition variable or something like that.

Comment: @user2357112 I am using multithreading. The boolean is_ok is a shared variable between threads, it will eventually change.

Comment: why are you trying to write a one liner for while loops ?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Real world problem :)

Comment: Python's grammar simply does not allow this. If you don't have a newline after the `:`, you must have a single simple statement, which itself *must* be followed by a newline. You can't put the `else` on the same line.

Comment: @MooingRawr I need to write these loop repeatedly in a thread, I want to save space.

Comment: Stop busywaiting. Use a real inter-thread communication mechanism, like a queue or a condition variable.

Comment: Also, that `else` is still completely pointless if you don't have a `break`. Multithreading doesn't change that.

Comment: I don't get it. What this 'else' is related to? To the `while` condition? Then it will just terminate if it is not true.

Comment: @user2357112 Trust me, the break is useless, I have proved it.

Comment: @VíctorMartínez: I'm not saying you need a `break`; I'm saying you *don't* need an `else`.

Comment: @user2357112 eugene Sh. That's right guys! I do not need an else, sorry!

Comment: If you are trying to wait on another thread, this won't work in python because you will just hold onto the GIL. You need to use a multithreading communication mechanism. look in the threading module. wait, waitfor and notify might fit what you need

Answer (score 2):

While it is possible to write simple loops like

```
while not is_ok: pass
```

on one line, it is typically frowned upon as bad style. What is not even possible is to combine a more complicated loop like you want on one line. The Python grammar defines a while loop as

```
while_stmt: 'while' test ':' suite ['else' ':' suite]
suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
```

Note that the `suite`, which precedes `else`, must either be an indented block starting on the following line, or a `;`-delimited sequence of (small) statements terminated by a newline. Either way, the `else` can't be on the same line as the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `while-else` construct is not supposed to be a one-liner as per idiomatic Python. The `else` block is executed only if the `while` condition turns `False`. So, instead of writing code like this:

```
while condition1:
    if condition2:
        break
if not condition1:
    print('I am here because condition1 is False')
```

You write it as follows, to improve readability (although **Luciano Ramalho** does point out in his book **Fluent Python** that `then` instead of `else` would have been a better choice of a keyword considering the semantics of this construct):

```
while condition1:
    if condition2:
        break
else:
    print('I am here because condition1 is False')
```

Your usage of the `while` loop does not comply with this structure. So, you are unnecessarily making your code complex.

Next, I would like to point out that there are at least two big problems with your original code segment.

1. Your implementation is that of a busy-wait, which is just a waste of CPU resource. Instead you should use a synchronization primitive such as a condition variable or semaphore.
2. If you are using one of the more popular Python interpreters, i.e., CPython or PyPy, the implications are much worse. Since these interpreters do not support running multiple software threads on multiple logical CPUs (which could be either multithreaded cores or multiple cores), you have to rely on the OS to preempt this thread and have it schedule the thread (or one of the threads) that sets `is_ok` to `True`.